# How do I interpret logit?

Tags: logit

I have been recommended the logit link for data in (0,1) since it's interpretable... how?

I am using the logit link function for data which is continuous (i.e., this is not logistic regression ... think beta regression.)
That is, I have the following model$$EY_i = \mu\\ g(\mu) = X\beta \\g(x) = \text{logit}(x)$$
and $Y_i$ is some suitable distribution, like the beta.

Then, we have $$\mu = \frac{e^{X\beta}}{1 + e^{X\beta}}$$

How is this interpretable? Meaning, if I gave you one particular $\beta_i$ of one particular covariate, how would you interpret it?

Comment: Have you Googled this?

Comment: The clearest explanation I have seen is [here](http://www.jerrydallal.com/lhsp/logistic.htm).

Comment: A better question is "why ever fit a logistic model when relative risk is an option" https://www.mailman.columbia.edu/research/population-health-methods/relative-risk-regression

Answer (score 3):

This is a really rudimentary question. Any book talks about logistic regression would cover for it.

If you are looking for some recommendations, I would [this tutorial](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/logit-regression/) for logistic regression (UCLA IRDE LOGIT REGRESSION | R DATA ANALYSIS EXAMPLES).

Here are some examples of interpretation from the tutorial:

> - For every one unit change in GRE, the log odds of admission (versus non-admission) increases by 0.002.
> - For a one unit increase in GPA, the log odds of being admitted to graduate school increases by 0.804.

To summarize, the connection is

- $X\beta$ gives Log Odds
- $\exp(X\beta)$ gives Odds
- $\text{logit}^{-1}(X \beta)$ gives Probability

So, if $X$ change, we can calculate how the probability change. Because the change is non-linear, sometimes, it is more intuitive to explain using "Log odds" or "Odds".

Comment: +1 except you mean logit inverse in the last line. I also would interpret effects on the log odds scale, but at least transform to the odds scale by exponentiating $\beta$. Lastly, I wouldn't say that admission probability *increased* for a one unit *change* in GRE because that is a within subject interpretation. A between subject interpretation appropriate for independent data analysis is: "comparing applicants whose GRE scores differed by one unit, the odds ratio of admission was $e^{\hat{\beta}}$."